# How to filter inside map in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
static final List<String> ALL_TYPES = AuthInt.getScopeAssociations().stream()
    .map(a -> a.getLeft().getSimpleName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There is a name "**MarieAntra**" in the the list which i want to add as **Marie** only .. How can i achieve this with Streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `map` you can write a whole function as long as it returns the correct type, so there's no reason you couldn't write something as

```java
static final List<String> ALL_TYPES = AuthInt.getScopeAssociations().stream()
  .map(a -> a.getLeft().getSimpleName())
  .map(name -> "MarieAntra".equals(name) ? "Marie" : name)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to simply extract a method with that logic

```
public static String filterString(String s){
    return s.equals("MarieAntra") ? "Marie" : s;
}
```

and used on the `Stream` as follows:

```
AuthInt.getScopeAssociations().stream()
                              .map(a -> filterString(a))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or just directly on the `Stream`:

```
AuthInt.getScopeAssociations()
    .stream()
    .map(a -> a.getLeft().getSimpleName().equals("MarieAntra") 
                     ? "Marie" 
                     : a.getLeft().getSimpleName()
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `map` you can write a whole function as long as it returns the correct type, so there's no reason you couldn't write something as

```
List<String> ALL_TYPES = AuthInt.getScopeAssociations().stream()

    .map(a -> {
                  if ("MarieAntra".equals(a.getLeft().getSimpleName())) return "Marie";
                  return a.getLeft().getSimpleName()
              }
   ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```